# Lua issue - Loading a library file before running

Tags: c, lua

I'm loading a Lua script to be run multiple times and another Lua script that acts as a library that is supposed to be used by the first script.

Let HelloWorldAPI.lua :

```
function HelloWorld()
    return "Hello world"
end
```

And SomeScript.lua :

```
HelloWorld()
```

I'm doing things in the following order :

```
L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs( L );
luaL_loadfile( L, "HelloWorldAPI.lua" );
luaL_loadfile( L, "SomeScript.lua" );
...
lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 )
...
lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 )
...
```

(some pieces of code were removed to keep it simple)

But I'm geting an error saying that I'm trying to call a nil value when calling the HelloWorld function.

Why ?

The function that I declared when the lib script was executed should be global and thus available in SomeScript.lua, right ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why is this tagged as `C` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`luaL_loadfile();` loads and compiles a chunk, puts it on top of the stack, but does not execute it yet (so, after the first call to `luaL_loadfile` the function `HelloWorld` is *not* yet defined in the global lua state.

Then, you load the file `SomeScript.lua`, which is now on top of the stack. The call to `lua_pcall` now executes this chunk at the top, which tries to call the (not yet) defined function `HelloWorld`, resulting in the error you observe.

With this in mind, that would be the correct order:

```
luaL_loadfile( L, "HelloWorldAPI.lua" );
lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 );
luaL_loadfile( L, "SomeScript.lua" );
lua_pcall( L, 0, 0, 0 );
```

However, to load *and* immediately execute a file you should use `luaL_dofile`:

```
luaL_dofile( L, "HelloWorldAPI.lua" );
luaL_dofile( L, "SomeScript.lua" );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I'm not using dofile because I'm wrapping all this into an object which loads/parses the script once and runs it many times. This allows me to avoid loading the script everytime it needs to be run.

Comment: @Virus721 Instead of writing your own solution, consider using the `require` function, and configuring it via `package.path` and/or `package.loaders`.

Answer (score 0):

`luaL_loadfile` leaves the compiled script as a function on the stack.

So, the function for `SomeScript.lua` is at the top, the function for `HelloWorldAPI.lua` is below it.

Comment: Thanks for your help.